# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta + 1/\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$ a radical extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

[image]

I am trying to answer part (d). I know the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ is:

$f(x)=x^3+x^2-2x-1$ which has roots: $\alpha, \alpha^2-2$ and $-\alpha^2-\alpha+1$.

so $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=3$

so if this extension is radical then some power of $\alpha$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ as there are no intermediate fields as their dimension would have to divide 3.

Now I know that $f(x)$ is soluble which, I think, implies that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is soluble and so is contained in a radical field.

Also if $\alpha^n = a \in \mathbb{Q},    n\ge 1$ then $f(x)\mid x^n-a$

I have tried $\alpha^7$ as this seems like an obvious choice but it is hard to simply a massive polynomial and it's not clear its in $\mathbb{Q}$
but from here I'm stumped.

Comment: It need not be the case that some power of $\alpha$ is in $\mathbb Q$... It is true that if we adjoin cube roots $\rho$ of unity to $\mathbb Q$, then a cyclic degree-three extension is generated by _some_ $\beta$ with $\beta^3\in\mathbb Q(\rho)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K/\Bbb Q$ were radical, there would be some $a\in\Bbb Q$ such that $\sqrt[3]a$ is irrational and would belong to $K$(why?). As $K/\Bbb Q$ is Galois and $K\leq\Bbb R$ this gives a contradiction.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate answer.

Comment: each answer uses a different notation for the extension. I guess to make it clear depending which you are familiar with

Comment: Great. So to clarify the minimum polynomial of $3\sqrt{\alpha}$ would be $x^3-\alpha$ but this is separable since the extension is Galois which implies $\zeta 3\sqrt{\alpha}$ is in K but K is a real number field and $\zeta$ is irrational and this contradiction implies the extension is not radical

Comment: @answer404 $\zeta$, that is, a primitive 3rd root of unity,  is not real, therefore the contradiction.

Comment: ah yes I miss typed